# How to open UI Dialog on each function call?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dialog, jquery-ui-dialog

I want to open dialogbox each time when `OpenDialog()` method calls each time with its contents.

**Function:**

```
function OpenDialog(){
    $("#seeContent").dialog({
                autoOpen: "false",
                stack: "true",
                height: "600",
                width: "700",
                resizable: "false"
            });
}
```

**Function call:**

```
<input type="button" onclick="OpenDialog()">
```

`Note:` It works fine while first call, when second call it overrides the first one.

Comment: DO NOT mix with inline...Very bad habit.
Plus, we need more code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `clone()` helps me to create a copy of dialog. Following is my working code.

```
jQuery("#seeContent").clone().dialog(
            { autoOpen: "false",
              stack: "true",
              height: "600",
              width: "700",
              resizable: "false" }
  });
```

I posted this answer because i could help others.

Hope, it will helps you. Thanks. !!

Answer (score 1):

HTML:

```
<input type="button" id="open_dialog">
<div id="content"></div>
```

JS:

```
$('#open_dialog').click(function(){
var data = getData();     //Get new data
$('#content').html(data); //Replace old data
$('#content').dialog({    //Open dialog
     autoOpen: "false",
     stack: "true",
     height: "600",
     width: "700",
     resizable: "false"
    });
});
```

Essentially, every time you click to open the dialog new data should be loaded first then open the dialog.

Comment: bobthyasian - thanks for giving your important time but actually in my case i have **only one input button** and **data comes through webservice** as per selections, so it note possible solution for me. Is any other suggestions ??

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you mean, 'data comes through webservice'?

Comment: bobthyasian - In each call i am using web service to **GET** the data to XML & JSON format like that.

Comment: its not possible to put code on jsfiddle but i have edited my question with 2 additional methods.

Comment: Sorry to say, but that didn't really help. The scope of what you're doing is hard to understand without having a point of reference. But I'll update my answer to give you a better idea of how to go about doing what you want to do.

Comment: If you really need help that bad, feel free to email me.

Comment: Thanks a lot but i solved my problem. I also posted my answer so it helps others.